# (py)Mongo query that returns matching values grouped by related field?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

(feel free to rename question)

I have some data in a mongo collection that looks like:

```
{
    ...
    'tree_id': 'ABC123',
    'serial_id': 'XYZ789',
    ...
}
```

From a json request, I end up with a whole slew of serial_id values (call them `wantedIDs`). I need to create (in python), a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'tree_id_1': [...all the serial_ids that matched tree_id_1...],
 'tree_id_2': [...all the serial_ids that matched tree_id_2...],
 ...}
```

I can do something like:

```
myMap = defaultdict(list)
for doc in client.database.collection.find({'serial_id': {'$in': wantedIDs}}):
    myMap[doc['tree_id']].append(doc['serial_id'])
```

I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic or mongorific way of doing this though? I'm a pretty novice pymongo user. I'm also curious at what point the `$in` isn't the way to go, if ever. The list of `wantedIDs` could be pretty big.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic or mongorific way of doing this though?

Yes, there is. Look for the [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). Pymongo collections have an `aggregate` method for the kind of operation you are attempting to perform (**see update**).

> I'm also curious at what point the $in isn't the way to go, if ever.

Well, I'm not entirely sure about `$in`, but I think you can put data in there until the BSON document size limit is reached, which is 16 megabytes. In any case, I would advise against coming close to this limit, since it will probably slow down your application and also the MongoDB server.

**Update**

Aggregation won't help with the potentially large `$in` problem. The same query used by `find` would go in the `$match` operator of the aggregation pipeline, so the same restrictions apply.

One thing you could do is simply not filter by `serial_id` at all if you detect that the list of `wantedIDs` is too large, either because it would hit the BSON limit, or because it would cause MongoDB to scan almost the entire collection.

You could also perform a single aggregation in MongoDB and bring the entire mapping of tree IDs into the application, and then do the matching in Python code. The result of that aggregation also cannot exceed the BSON maximum document size. If the collection does not change much, you might try to cache the aggregation result to improve performance.

Of course, all of this could be premature optimizations. Without knowing the details of the collection/application, it is difficult to tell.

Other than that, there is not much more you can do without rethinking the application or restructuring the data to avoid `$in` entirely.

Comment: My queries might be bigger at times, but are a long way away from 16MB. A very long way. So I'm just going to put to that worry to bed. I'm off to see if I can figure out how to put the aggregate together.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation framework can get you close:

```
>>> db.collection.insert({'tree_id': 'ABC123', 'serial_id': 1})
ObjectId('52b105e3ca1ce9bb42202f63')
>>> db.collection.insert({'tree_id': 'ABC123', 'serial_id': 2})
ObjectId('52b105e4ca1ce9bb42202f64')
>>> db.collection.insert({'tree_id': '2', 'serial_id': 1})
ObjectId('52b105f8ca1ce9bb42202f65')
>>> db.collection.aggregate([{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$tree_id',
        'serial_ids': {'$push': '$serial_id'}
     }
}])
{u'ok': 1.0,
    u'result': [{u'_id': u'2', u'serial_ids': [1]},
                {u'_id': u'ABC123', u'serial_ids': [1, 2]}
    ]
}
```

From here, finish it up in Python:

```
dict([(row['_id'], row['serial_ids']) for row in result['result']])
```